# System.FormatException: 'An error occurred while deserializing the property. Using aggregate function with the help of mongoDB.Driver C #

Tags: c#, mongodb, lookup, aggregates

**Is there have any way to combine to collections from MongoDB C#**

> I think the problem with @as...

[image: Created the main class which contains combinations of mail class and profile class. But different error]

> Created the main class which contains combinations of mail class and profile class. But different error.

[image: In Studio 3T I am getting data]

> In Studio 3T I am getting data

**Models are shown below**

[image: Model 1]

[image: model 2]

[image: model 3]

[image: model 4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var Result = await MailCollection.Aggregate()
            .Lookup(
            foreignCollection: ProfileCollection,
            localField: e => e.SenderID,
            foreignField: f => f.Id,
            @as: (MailInfo profile) => profile.SenderInfo
            ).ToListAsync();
```

> SenderInfo property changed to `List<Profile>`

[image]